# Does the phrasing 'ever so' always possess an ironic undertone?

Tags: meaning, connotation

Well, the question is up in the title.

Does the phrasing 'ever so' always possess an ironic undertone?

I've seen this wording especially in rather aged literature, as some short stories by Bradbury or similiar stuff.

The reason I believe there is such an undertone, is merely because I found a n according note on dict.cc by chance

https://www.dict.cc/?s=ever+so

Comment: I'm sure the pejorative sense derives from the increasing obsolescence of the phrase in its sincere sense. However, I'm not convinced its sincere sense has died out, especially in British usage.

Comment: The undertone of a word is often *ever so* subtle, and usually the larger context has *ever such* an influence on the undertone of a single expression. When we are speaking, tone of voice and body language create *ever so* much undertone. The word *always* is ever so futile when discussing language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly *can* be used ironically, and maybe today it is more than in the past, but when you ask if it's *always* used that way, the answer has to be **no**.

Answer (score 2):

'Ever so' has the connotation of being spoken by an upper class English or American person from an old fashioned (black and white!) film.  A similar word but with stronger connotations might be 'frightful' as an adjective or 'frightfully' as an adverb e.g. 'he was a frightful brute.'

With these old fashioned and upper class connotations which are almost comic, it could certainly be used ironically or by someone assuming the persona of such a speaker to create an effect, which could be irony.

However, to specifically answer the question, no it certainly does not always imply irony.

Comment: My connotation is the exact opposite. It sounds dialectal, quaint, and lower-class old-fashioned to me (think servants in _Downton Abbey_ or the lower-class characters in a Miss Marple novel).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it does. I have seen it used just for emphasis.